# ¿Puedo guardar un operador como variable?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

```
const addition = (num1, num2) => num1 + num2;

const subtraction = (num1, num2) => num1 - num2;

const multiplication = (num1, num2) => num1 * num2;

const division = (num1, num2) => num1 / num2;

const command = {
  add: addition,
  subtract: subtraction,
  multiply: multiplication,
  division,
  execute: function(action, { num1, num2 }) {
    return this[action](num1, num2);
  }
};

const calculate = (action, numbers) => {
  const result = command.execute(action, numbers);
  console.log(
    `In ${action} of numbers ${Object.values(numbers)} the result is ${result}`
  );
};

calculate('add', { num1: 2, num2: 3 });
```

El primer código es el ejemplo que he hecho de el patrón comando y haciéndolo me surgió la duda de que si todas las funciones son iguales solo cambia el operador si podría cambiar el command a alguna forma como el segundo por ejemplo para quitar las funciones pero he estado mirando y no encuentro nada

```
const command = {
  add: '+',
  subtract: '-',
  multiply: '*',
  division: '/',
  execute: function(action, { num1, num2 }) {
    return num1 this[action] numb2;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Se puede si lo guardas como *string* y lo ejecutas usando `eval()`, o con el constructor `Function()`

```js
const command = {
  add: "+",
  subtract: "-",
  multiply: "*",
  division: "/",
  execute: function(action, { num1, num2 }) {
    return eval(num1+this[action]+num2)
  }
};

const calculate = (action, numbers) => {
  const result = command.execute(action, numbers);
  console.log(
    `In ${action} of numbers ${Object.values(numbers)} the result is ${result}`
  );
};

calculate('add', { num1: 2, num2: 3 });
calculate('subtract', { num1: 2, num2: 3 });
calculate('multiply', { num1: 2, num2: 3 });
calculate('division', { num1: 2, num2: 3 });
```

Usar `eval()` o `Function()` no es recomendable por una serie de potenciales problemas, ver [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea).

`Function()` funciona un poco distinto, tendría que ser algo como esto:

```js
var action = '+'
var execute = (action, {num1, num2}) => new Function("x", "y", `return ${num1} ${action} ${num2}`)(action, num1,num2);

console.log(execute(action, {num1:3,num2:2}));
```

Answer (score 0):

No puedes guardar operadores en las variables, lo que quieres hacer no es imposible, pero no como tu esperas que sea.

Puedes guardar el `action` en una variable y después condicionarla.

```
execute: function(action, { num1, num2 }) {
  if( this[action] == '+' ) return num1 + num2
  if( this[action] == '-' ) return num1 - num2
  if( this[action] == '/' ) return num1 / num2
  if( this[action] == '*' ) return num1 * num2

  // operador de Resto o Residuo (no es porcentaje)
  if( this[action] == '%' ) return num1 % num2

  // otra 'action'
  return 0
}
```

Comment: Las preguntas y respuestas deben ser concretas, sin saludos, firmas ni nada que no sea necesario. Ref. [¿Cuál es la conducta esperada de los usuarios?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). Si quieres ser cálido / amable, puedes usar los comentarios para dar la bienvenida, saludar dar parabienes, etc.

Comment: Bueno, cuando escribi la respuesta me aparecia un mensaje que decia "Fulano es un usuario nuevo, se amable", ya está.

Answer (score 0):

Estrictamente hablando, no es posible guardar un operador como variable pero puedes guardar los caracteres que representan los operadores como cadenas (Strings), en términos de [lego](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_(no_profesional)) (en inglés layperson, layman), sí se puede.

Podrías usar `eval` ejecutar código JavaScript representado como texto. Ejemplo:

```js
/**
 * Ejecutar una operación binaria
 *
 * @param {String} operador Operador binario (+, -, *, /, %, **)
 * @param {Array} operandos Matriz de elementos en los que se aplica la operación, deben ser 2
 */
function calculo(operador, operandos){
  return eval(operandos[0] + operador + operandos[1]);
}

// Suma
console.info(calculo('+',[1,2]));
// Resta
console.info(calculo('-',[1,2]));
// Multiplicación
console.info(calculo('*',[1,2]));
// División
console.info(calculo('/',[1,2]));
// Residuo
console.info(calculo('%',[1,2]));
// Exponente
console.info(calculo('**',[1,2]));
```